# Using a RecyclerView to call Fragment Transactions

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listfragment

I don't know if this is a trivial issue but, I couldn't find information about it anywhere else. How does one execute `Fragment` transactions to replace `Fragments` when a `RecyclerView` item is clicked. Normally you would extend the `Fragment` class but I can't because the `RecyclerAdapter` class already extends  `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `ItemClickListener` interface and use it to notify the fragment when an item has been clicked. You can do the fragment transaction in the fragment.

You can find a full project with a code sample [here](https://bitbucket.org/StylingAndroid/material/src/cb52f6306762a76265e1305caed6a1786dba1e32/mobile/src/main/java/com/stylingandroid/materialrss/adapter/FeedAdapter.java?at=Part5). Courtesy of the Styling Android blog.

Answer (score 0):

You Should be use following code;

```
                FragmentTransaction manager = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.blank_frame,detailGoogleFragment);
```